kpathsea can't find `cmssbx8`
I compiling the following code (pdflatex t.tex) in TeXLive (Opensuse 15.6)
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ub{\vec{\mathbf{u}}}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\begin{document}
$D_{\ub}$
\end{document}

I get the following message
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input cmssbx8
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2021/TeX Live for SUSE Linux) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf cmssbx8
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktex.opt: línea 63: cd: /home/test: No es un directorio
! I can't find file `cmssbx8'.
<*> ...jfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input cmssbx8
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...jfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input cmssbx8
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: cmssbx8.log: No existe el fichero o el directorio
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input cmssbx8' failed to make cmssbx8.tfm.
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktex.opt: línea 63: cd: /home/test: No es un directorio
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \csname\endcsname=cmssbx8 at 7.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not f
ound.
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  
l.6 \end{document}

Doing locate cmssbx8 shows
/usr/share/fonts/texlive-sansmathfonts/cmssbx8.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/sansmathfonts/cmssbx8.pfb

So kpathsea don't find the file, but it exist. I have tried latexmk -pdf paper.tex (as the answer to this question suggest) but shows the same message.
Changing the $D_{\ub}$ by $\ub$ compiles correctly. Does someone knows what's going on?
I did cd /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/sansmathfonts/cmssbx8.pfb and then (sudo) mktexmf cmssbx8 and runs correctly (also with the file at /usr/share/fonts/texlive-sansmathfonts/cmssbx8.pfb), but keep throwing the same error.

Runaway argument?
{\vec {\mathbf {u}} \usepackage {sansmathfonts} \begin {document} $D_\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of @argdef.

in an up to date texlive if I add the missing } metafont is succesfully run automatically and generates .../texmf-var/fonts/tfm/public/sauter/cmssbx8.tfm

I'm not sure how suse linux packages texlive but you want sauter fonts so something like this https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=texlive-sauterfonts  installed via your normal linux package manager

@DavidCarlisle Didn't understand the first two comments, but the last one solved the problem: the package sauter was missing. Thank you! How did you notice this package was missing?

I ran your test document (always good to have a test document:-)  here and saw that it made a font using the sauter fonts, then googled for where they were in linux packages. As for the first comment if you try the code you posted you will get the error that I showed not the error you asked about as there is a missing }  at the end of the \newcommand

Oh I got it! Didn't see the missing }.

By default cmssbx will be made (by metafont not as a scalable type 1 font) using the sauter extension to the computer modern family. Thus your example will run if you install texlive-sauterfonts using your linux package manager (as you are using a SUSE Linux packaged texlive)
